# Get the last record in object array javaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object array like below. Is there anyway to get the latest record from this. (ex:- if the latest record is sunday[1], how can i get it  )

```
const days: {
sunday: {
0: {duty: {…}, name: "Anna"}
1: {duty: {…}, name: "Mike"}
}, 
monday: {…}, 
tuesday: {…}, 
wednesday: {…}, 
}
```

Comment: This is not an `Array`. It is a property of some `Object`.
Please provide a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: How would the program know which record is the latest? You could get the one with the highest index for a certain day but it sounds like you want to actually get the one that was last added overall - but for this, there is information missing. You'd need to first have a timestamp stored in each record so you could figure out which one is highest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys(..).length` to get the highest of the object

```js
const days = {
  sunday: {
    0: {name: "Anna"},
    1: {name: "Mike"}
  }
};

const day = days["sunday"];
const last = day[Object.keys(day).length - 1];
console.log(last);
```